# How is the Super Bowl halftime musician and show determined?

Tags: live-music

[Rihanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Super_Bowl_halftime_shows) is headlining this year's Super Bowl Halftime show. Who selects the musician each year, and what is the process for selecting the headliner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The selection process begins with a panel which includes officials such as the NFL’s director of entertainment, folks from the NFL’s production company, and the halftime show’s director and producer. After a long and detailed process, the shortlist is handed over to the Super Bowl’s hosting city for a final decision.

Read more at: https://www.charlotteobserver.com/charlottefive/c5-people/article258383208.html#storylink=cpy

---

In terms of what the selection *criteria* is:

> Halftime show performers are selected on account of several elements. Genre relevance and popularity are the two most important factors to consider when a shortlist for performers is being made, but choosing headliners is about more than just numbers — it’s about making a statement.

Read more at: https://www.charlotteobserver.com/charlottefive/c5-people/article258383208.html#storylink=cpy

or also

> the league considers popularity, music genre, and the artists’ overall performance value. So even though Mick Jagger and the Rolling Stones were at the peak of their powers in the late 1960s, they didn’t have a broad enough appeal to play at the Super Bowl (not they would have wanted to play anyway).
> So the league starts with popular performers who appeal to as many people as possible and goes from there.

Read more [here](https://www.sportscasting.com/heres-how-the-nfl-chooses-the-super-bowl-halftime-performers/)

Comment: Yep. Super Bowl halftime commercials are the most expensive time on TV by a landslide. So, essentially, the artist performing at the Super Bowl halftime show is chosen by the amount of viewers they can attract to the commercials.